# Cameron-Martin space for $\ell^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal B=\ell^2$ and let $\xi_n$ be i.i.d. standard normal random variables and consider the sequence $\mathbf{g}= (a_1 \xi_1, a_2 \xi_2,...)$. By Hairer's notes, exercise 3.5, (https://www.hairer.org/notes/SPDEs.pdf) we have that the law of $\mathbf{g}$ is a Gaussian measure on $\mathcal B=\ell^2$. I am interested in its Cameron-Martin space, which is defined as the closure of the space

$$\mathring{\mathcal H}_\mu=\{\{h_n\}\in \mathcal B: \exists \{h_n^\ast\}\in \mathcal B, C_\mu(h^\ast,\ell)=\ell(h) \forall \ell \in \mathcal B\}.$$

I suspect that the space above is the set of all $\mathbf h=\{a_n^2 b_n\}$ for some square summable sequence $\{b_n\}$. That is because for each $\mathbf h =\{a_n^2 b_n\}$, we associate the sequence $\mathbf h^\ast=\{b_n\}$ and for arbitrary $\ell=\{y_n\}$ we have

$$E[\langle \mathbf h^\ast, \mathbf g\rangle\langle \ell, \mathbf g\rangle]= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2b_n y_n=\langle \ell, \mathbf h\rangle.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @G.Chiusole It's just that the square is throwing me off. I suspect it should be $a_n b_n$. What is the Cameron-Martin norm in this case?

Comment: @Rpthoughs The Cameron-Martin norm will be $\Vert h \Vert_H = \sum_{n =1}^{\infty} a_n^{-2} h_n^2$. This is since $\Vert \cdot \Vert_H = \Vert \cdot \Vert_{L^2}$ (with the appropriate identifications). The square comes from the fact that the sequence $a$ from the definition of $\mathbf{g}$ enters the expression for the norm bilinearly, not just linearly.

Comment: By $L^2$ I mean $L^2(\mathcal{B}, \mu)$

Comment: @G.Chiusole Thank you for your help.